# Installing wine-overwatch: "Something went wrong trying to create a directory"

Tags: permissions, wine

I'm attempting to follow [these instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-play-overwatch-on-linux-with-wine) for installing Overwatch on Ubuntu 16.04.

The only difference is instead of installing to my home drive (which is networked), I'm installing to a local `/shared/$USER/` which I have permissions on. ($USER variable wasn't working so I had to use the username directly)

When I get to the install step, by running:

```
WINEPREFIX='/home/myuser/.overwatch' WINE='/shared/myuser/wine-overwatch/bin/wine64' /shared/myuser/wine-overwatch/bin/wine64 /shared/myuser/Downloads/Overwatch-Setup.exe
```

I get the installer popping up with this error:

> Something went wrong trying to create a directory
>   ("C:/ProgramData/Battle.new/Agent"). Please ensure you have permission
>   to create the directory and try again.

Where is this directory so I can check permissions?

Here are the permissions on `/shared/myuser`

```
:/shared/myuser$ ls -al
total 6152596
drwxr-xr-x  7 myuser 10043       4096 Dec  5 13:28 .
drwxrwxrwx  4 root  root        4096 Dec  5 13:25 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser 10043    3949552 Dec  5 13:25 Overwatch-Setup.exe
drwxr-xr-x 13 myuser 10043       4096 Jun 28 09:41 .PlayOnLinux
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser 10043       4096 May 30  2017 steamapps
drwxr-xr-x  6 myuser 10043       4096 Sep 22 11:59 wine-overwatch
```

Answer (score 0):

In Wine, `C:` translates by default to `drive_c` in the Wine prefix, so `C:/ProgramData/Battle.new/Agent` is `/home/myuser/.overwatch/drive_c/ProgramData/Battle.new/Agent`.